# Filtering partitioned tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a DAY partitioned table in bigquery where I want to remove rows in which a certain column value is duplicated (I only want the last such value, ordered by a timestamp column). Now since the bigquery DML language doesn't support partitioned tables (and has other limitations), I think what I need to do is to create a temporary table that is a filtered view of the original, delete the original and then perform a copy of the temporary table to the original name and delete the temporary table. I can do this with something like this:

`SELECT * EXCEPT(row_number)
FROM (
  SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER()
          OVER (PARTITION BY partition_col order by time_col desc)
          row_number
  FROM my_partioned_table
)
WHERE row_number = 1`

But how do I preserve the partitioning information with this approach?

If I copy a complete table, portioning information is preserved but what do I do if i want to to create effectively a filtered view of a table that also preserves partitioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point if your changes are across multiple partitions, you'll need to run a query for each partition separately.

1. Create temporary table as partitioned.
2. Run a query that returns you a filtered view of the table, one partition at a time (with a filter on _PARTITIONTIME) and append to the right partition of the temporary table. (for example, destination table would be table$20170115 if you are working on the partition for 20170115)
3. Copy from temporary table to the final result table, partitioning information is expected to be preserved on table copy.